# "PKGBUILD does not exist" when running "makepkg -cf"

Tags: arch-linux, pkgbuild, makepkg

When I run `makepkg -cf`, I get an error:

```
==> ERROR: PKGBUILD does not exist.
```

[image]

But if I run `makepkg -p PKGBUILD.asc` it works.

[image]

Can someone explain to me someone why the first doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How I solved it**

---

The problem is that when downloading `PKGBUILD`, the browser added an unwanted extension to the file which turned out to be `PKGBUILD` becoming `PKGBUILD.asc`, the solution is to simply remove the file extension i.e. rename `PKGBUILD.asc` as `PKGBUILD`, you may have another extension that does not matter, the important thing is to remove it.

**For More Information**

---

`makepkg` is a script that automates the building of packages Arch. When you use it without telling it which file to build, you are essentially telling it do nothing, which leaves you with the error you see here.

This error explains it is trying to call `PKGBUILD` which is a package build description file that needs to be made before the package is built by `makepkg`. When you used the `-p` flag you are telling `makepkg` to instead build the package using `buildscript` in place of `PKGBUILD`

I highly suggest reading the man page for `makepkg` by running `man makepkg` so that you can learn more about this tool for future use. I will link it here for you as well https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/makepkg.8.html

Comment: thx, i was checking superficial the link that u send thx btw, i said that becouse the readme of the program that i want to install tell me to run `makepkg -cf` so if i want to run that command what i need to do if is something that need a path or something and not a short command line i ll read not superficial the link that u send. Thx

Comment: No problem, be sure to mark it as answered so it is easier for others to find that have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

## August 2023 update, another alternative

*If available, try a `-bin` package option.* Whatever you are trying to compile might already be compiled. That is one option, or not...

This has been a problem in the past for various reasons. Consider the forum on Arch...

- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=52118
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=154730
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=201265
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=143298

I was running `make -si` specifically for `yay` per the [install instructions on GitHub](https://github.com/Jguer/yay). Searching this out led me to this question, so others might have a question also.

Maybe something worked in the past and maybe some dependency broke an update, et cetera.

I solved the problem by changing from the `yay` repository to the `yay-bin` repository, per the same instructions page. That solved it.